# Scala match statements with inline regexes

Tags: regex, scala, string-matching

I am trying (if at all possible) to get a Scala match/case statement to perform an inline regex match for me.

Specifically, I have a method that will run a `match`, and if the input to the method starts with the string "fizz", then I would like the match statement to select the correct case:

```
def animalToSound(animal : String) : String = {
    animal match {
        case "duck"   =>    "quack"
        case "lion"   =>    "roar"
        case "dog"    =>    "woof"
        case matchesFizzRegex(animal) =>  "heyo!"
        case _        =>    "meow"
    }
}

def matchesFizzRegex(animal : String) : ??? = {
    val fizzRegex = "fizz*".r
    if(fizzRegex.match(animal)) {
        ???
    } else {
        ???
    }
}
```

So if I call `animalToSound("fizzBuzz")`, then the desired behavior is:

1. Does "fizzBuzz" equal "duck"? No. So try the next case.
2. Does "fizzBuzz" equal "lion"? No. So try the next case.
3. Does "fizzBuzz" equal "dog"? No. So try the next case.
4. Does "fizzBuzz" match the fizz regex (any string starting with 'fizz')? Yes, so return "heyo!"

Any ideas how I can get this working properly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Simple and straight forward**

Use `pattern matching with guards` and `matches` method of string

```
def animalToSound(animal : String) : String = animal match {
        case "duck"   =>    "quack"
        case "lion"   =>    "roar"
        case "dog"    =>    "woof"
        case x if x matches "fizz.*" =>  "heyo!"
        case _        =>    "meow"
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can match regex among other cases:

```
val reg = "fizz.*".r
animal match {
    case "duck"   =>    "quack"
    case "lion"   =>    "roar"
    case "dog"    =>    "woof"
    case `reg`    =>    "heyo!"
    case _        =>    "meow"
}
```